# Jenkins pipline checkout with a copy instead of git clone

Tags: git, copy, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

Folks,
I am searching around but cannot find the answer. I am having a terraform directory on my mac **'/Users/juergen/Documents/DPSCodeAcademy/Terraform/aws/DDVE6/ddve6-modulized/ddve6-deployment-modulized/DDOS 7.4 with EIP'** from which I wanna copy all tf files into my working directory.
This is working with git but now I wanna get the git replaced with a copy but do not know how to address the working dir which should be terraform in Jenkins. The old Jenkinsfile portion for git looks like this:

```
stages {
        stage('checkout') {
            steps {
                 script{
                        dir("terraform")
                        {
                            git "https://github.com/juergenschubert/DELLEMC-DPS-Jenkins.git"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And how to copy the Jenkinsfile as well into my workings dir upfront.
Thanks

Comment: Is it safe to assume the Jenkins bulld node is also your local device where the files are stored? That would be required for file copying your Terraform module. As for copying the `Jenkinsfile`, if that is the same one which defines the pipeline code itself, then you have a chicken and egg problem there. Maybe it would be better to ask what you want to achieve here, and find an easier way to solve the problem?

Comment: Jenkins host is my local macboook. Correct. What I am trying to archive to work with a local terraform directory insted of creating a github repository to pull from. So a copy was the easies way. Another way would be to point the workspace to this directory where tf files are located. Which I also don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins master and agent are running on Mac (not as a docker container) just use `cp` command like below

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('cp') {
            steps {
                dir("x") {
                    sh "cp -r /source/path ." //dot represent current directory i.e. $WORKSPACE/x
                }
                sh "ls -al x"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your Jenkins run on a docker container on your mac docker runtime, make sure to attach a volume and copy from there.